# Jenkins integrating with Github Organization: on opened pull requests, only run build for pull request NOT for branches

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently using Jenkins CI with Github webhooks. I set up a view for my Github Organization. Jenkins is able to scan my organization for branches and pull requests and run builds on pull requests with Jenkinsfiles. This current discovery functionality is okay. However, when a new pull request gets opened on a repo, a build is run for both the branch, and the pull request. These are being done in separate workspaces as well. So in github, I see builds for `continuous-integration/jenkins/branch` and `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge`. I would only like to run the build for the pr-merge and not for branch. I can't seem to find any configuration options in Jenkins to tweak this.

It seems that I am looking for options specified in the `Github Branch Source Plugin` in [this section](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#_controlling_what_is_built). I have confirmed that the plugin is installed, but I can't find a way to modify these settings anywhere, neither in the GUI, nor `$JENKINS_HOME`.

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated. There's really no benefit for us to have a build log of all branches being used for pull requests, since they are later discarded.

Comment: So did you find any clean solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you add `Filter by name (with regular expression)` to `Behaviours` as `develop|PR-.*` it will stop triggering the pipeline for branches that doesn't match the pattern.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWpsG.png)

Comment: Works perfect! I wanted to keep builds on main branch, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can change the *Discover branches* strategy to exclude branches that are also filed as pull request:

[image]

Comment: This option is already currently selected, but builds for the `branch` and `pull request` still happen when a new pull request is open on Github.

Comment: Because the push to the branch directly triggers branch indexing, which then triggers the build? (and the PR is filed a minute afterwards?)

Comment: So what in addition can be changed to stop the build from happening on the branch as well as the PR? If the push to the branch was triggering a branch indexing, I would think that the option you mentioned above would not do any branch builds, but unfortunately thats not the case.

Answer (score 1):

**Discover Branches:** `Exclude branches that are also filed as PRs`

See **Controlling what is built** section on the documentation page for the **Github Branch Source** plugin page. https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#github-branch-source

Would also suggest if you have your GitHub repository configured for status checks you disable the branch status' that was generated so your PR only depends on the PR status.  See GitHub doc: https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-status-checks/

Answer (score 0):

If somebody comes comes across this post, here's my solution. I use Github App to handle triggers for me, described [here](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-admin-guide/github-app-auth) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDmeeVDrp0o). In addition to running branch builds, Jenkins creates a new dedicated branch to build PR(named like PR-45). I really don't need that. So here are the steps to have branch builds linked to your PRs and drop PR builds completely:

1. Unsubscribe your app from Pull Request events (don't remove permission to read PRs though, only unsubscribe from Pull Request events): https://github.com/organizations/myorg/settings/apps/myjenkins-reader-app/permissions
2. Change branch protection rules in Github repository to only require checks on branch builds, not PR builds
   [image]
3. In your Multibranch Jenkins pipeline, configure Github source  to discover *All branches* and to exclude branches starting with PR- [image: Jenkins Screenshot]